# Scrolling down plays the video. Scrolling up rewinds the video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I don't really know how to use this. I tried copy the js to my js folder and link it is not able to use. It need something like bower.
[Scrolling](https://github.com/develodesign/play-on-scroll#play-html-videos-on-scroll)

As you can see here this is the example that I want.
[Example](https://www.apple.com/macbook/)

Maybe there have other js can do this. Or any keywords that I can use? Thanks.

Comment: first thing, you can use it without bower also. That should not be the problem.

Comment: what problem are you facing? Can you share your code snippet?